# mongo spark connector 10 does not support deduplication of uploaded duplicate data well

Tags: pyspark

I use mongo spark connector 10.1, pyspark 3.2.3
connector version 10.1 only supports 'overwrite' and 'append' modes. Set the unique composite index in mongodb to avoid duplication. After writing in 'overwrite' mode (regardless of whether there is duplicate data) the unique index on mongodb will disappear. After writing in 'append' mode Spark workers with duplicate data report an error directly.

My expectation: write duplicate data to mongo, update or ignore it instead of throwing an exception or deleting the original unique index
Can you help me, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.